# Understanding Apache Spark filter transformation behavior

Tags: java, apache-spark, filter

I have a list of items in a JavaRDD, where every item is a date (Java Calendar). Now, I want to filter all the dates that are less than a given date. That's my code:

main

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Date comparison test")
            .setMaster("local[4]").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        // initializes a filter date to 01/01/2016 at 10:00:00
        Calendar filterDate = Calendar.getInstace();
        filterDate.clear();
        filterDate.setTimeInMillis(1451642400000l);

        // initializes an array of 40 calendars, in which every date
        // is 1 hour later than the previous, starting from
        // 01/01/2016 at 08:00:00
        ArrayList<Calendar> calendarArray = new ArrayList<>();
        // milliseconds corresponding to 01/01/2016 at 08:00:00
        long initial = 1451635200000l;
        for(int i=0; i < 40; ++i) {
            Calendar one = Calendar.getInstace();
            one.clear();
            one.setTimeInMillis(initial);
            calendarArray.add(one);
            initial += 3600000;
        }

        JavaRDD<Calendar> rdd = sc.parallelize(calendarArray);
        JavaRDD<Calendar> rddFiltered = rdd.filter(new FilterTest(filterDate));
        System.out.println("RDD SIZE " + rddFiltered.count());
        sc.close();
}
```

FilterTest code

```
public class FilterTest implements Function<Calendar, Boolean> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3134317182912968444L;
private final Calendar filteringDate;

public FilterTest_(Calendar filteringDate) {
    super();
    this.filteringDate = filteringDate;
}

@Override
public Boolean call(Calendar arg0) throws Exception {
    // getStandardFormattedDate just prints a date in a given format
    System.out.println(TimeUtils.getStandardFormattedDate(arg0) + " - " + TimeUtils.getStandardFormattedDate(filteringDate));
    if(arg0.before(filteringDate)) {
        return false;
    }
    else { 
        return true;    
    }
  }
}
```

What I can't really understand is the output I get. It seems like the fixed calendar I pass as the parameter to compare with changes sometimes (like when it's `Sat, 01 Jan 2016 22:00:00`).

Output

```
Sat, 01 Jan 2016 08:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Sat, 01 Jan 2016 08:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 08:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Sat, 02 Jan 2016 15:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 09:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 09:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Sat, 02 Jan 2016 15:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 09:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Sat, 02 Jan 2016 20:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00 - Fri, 02 Jan 2016 07:00:00
Sat, 02 Jan 2016 17:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 11:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Sat, 02 Jan 2016 21:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00 - Sat, 01 Jan 2016 22:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 22:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Sat, 01 Jan 2016 22:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 12:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 23:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 23:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 23:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00 - Fri, 02 Jan 2016 00:00:00
Sat, 02 Jan 2016 00:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 19:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 13:00:00 - Fri, 02 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Sat, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00 - Sat, 01 Jan 2016 14:00:00
Sat, 02 Jan 2016 01:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00 - Fri, 02 Jan 2016 11:00:00
Sat, 01 Jan 2016 14:00:00 - Fri, 02 Jan 2016 11:00:00
Sat, 02 Jan 2016 11:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 15:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 15:00:00 - Sat, 02 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Sat, 02 Jan 2016 02:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Sat, 02 Jan 2016 15:00:00 - Sat, 02 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 12:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 22:00:00
Sat, 01 Jan 2016 17:00:00 - Fri, 02 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 22:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Sat, 02 Jan 2016 13:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Sat, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
Sat, 02 Jan 2016 23:00:00 - Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00
```

What is exactly happening during the computation distribution to that variable? Also because apparently the result is correct, but I'm having trouble in debugging this code in a more complex situation.

Comment: It looks strange for me, how could you get the date after you clearing your `filterDate` in the `for` loop? After deleting that line, your code runs well for me

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy/paste error, `one` is the calendar to be initialised.  Actually the code works fine for me as well, but I can't understand the output.

Comment: the code works for me i meant my output gives me always the filterDate which i expected. your problem doesn't occur for me

Comment: I ran the same code on my cluster. On the cluster, the output is fine. When I run it on my local machine, I still get that output. That's incredibly strange. Even funnier, if I add another check as `Sytem.out.println(filteringDate.getTimeInMillis() + " : " + 1451642400000l)` just after the first syso in the `call()` method, it always prints the correct time in milliseconds, while the first syso prints out the wrong date as showed. I thought it was a problem of time zone, but apparently it's not. I'm really disconcerted.